Creating a transformation matrix for a 2d coordinate system with some known points
I have this system

There are 2 different coordinate spaces. one in red and one in blue.
I know the values of cp and p in the blue space.
I also know the value of x in the red space
But I want to create a transformation matrix so that I can convert any given point in the red system to the blue system.
I assumed that I could create and normalize a vector from p to cp
y = p -> cp
and place that in a 2d matrix like this
y.x, -y.y,
y.y, y.x

But it looks like something is missing or wrong.
To verify I have multiplied the matrix with p in the blue system, and I expected it to give me 0,0 but it doesn't. So I kind of feel like I am missing something pretty obvious.
And I guess the question is: is my thinking correct and if not, why?

Two different Cartesian coordinate systems in 2D are related by a rotate-shear matrix with 4 components plus a translation vector of
2 components. You need 6 independent values to determine such a relation uniquely.
